# how to detect circles of symbolic links in haskell

Tags: haskell, filesystems

i understand that i can find circles in symbolic links with the

```
find . -follow -printf ""
```

command (and other similar methods on the command line as previously [previously suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/265598/how-do-i-find-circular-symbolic-links/265614#265614). but i cannot find a command in haskell to achieve the same.

there are several operations in System.Directory (eg createDirectory, renameDirectory) to return the ELOOP error from the OS (for [linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Symbolic-Links.html)), but none to simply check a filepath for a circle of symbolic links. but none to simply to check a filepath.

Comment: So you mean cycles in file systems?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unix` package's [`readSymbolicLink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:readSymbolicLink) to implement this check.

Comment: This is currently beyond what I am used to do in Haskell - I have not yet touched FFI yet. May come.

Comment: @user855443 The `unix` package author already did all the necessary FFI work -- you don't need to touch the FFI yourself to use this.

Comment: thank you - on first reading, I did not realize it was already on hackage